# How do I find the rotation matrix between 2 normalized vectors coming from the origin

Tags: matrices, geometry, rotations

In my project, I have two vectors a normal vector $(0,0,1)$ (this is up in the program I'm using), and another normalized vector $(x,y,z)$. Suppose I rotate $(0,0,1)$ to a new $(a,b,c)$ which is also a normalized vector from the origin, how do I find the position of the new $(x,y,z)$ which rotated along with it. What I think might work is finding the rotation matrix between $(0,0,1)$ and $(a,b,c)$ and applying that rotation matrix to $(x,y,z)$, but I don't know how to find the rotation matrix between them. Below is an example, the red is $(0,0,1)$ in case 1 and $(a,b,c)$ in the rest of them, and blue is $(x,y,z)$ and $(x', y', z')$(or what I think $(x',y',z')$ is).

[image]

Also if it is indeed the rotation matrix between $(0,0,1)$ and $(a,b,c)$ that is being applied to $(x,y,z)$ I think it should be the simplest rotation matrix from $(0,0,1)$ to $(a,b,c)$, because if I'm not wrong there should be infinitely many rotation matrices between those two.

The motion of the rotation also matters, as I want $(0,0,1)$ to move to $(a,b,c)$ along a plane, as demonstrated below. The drawn orange vector on the right is perpendicular to this plane.
[image]

Comment: You didn't mention axis of rotation and also angle of rotation

Comment: Ah, on second thought, after reading the comment by Lost in Space: I am not sure if you are seeking a rotation so both vectors lie along the same plane or along a different axis...

Comment: @quanticbolt I'm really sorry but I don't understand what you mean by that.

Comment: @quanticbolt IDK if this is what you need but suppose a plane between $(0,0,1)$ and $(a,b,c)$ that passes through the origin(I think?) and $(0,0,1)$ moves on this plane to $(a,b,c)$

Comment: A problem is that there is no unique rotation that takes $(0,0,1)$ to $(a,b,c)$. If $R$ is one such rotation, and $S$ is an arbitrary rotaion with axes $(0,0,1)$, then the rotation $R\circ S$ still takes $(0,0,1)$ to $(a,b,c)$. Your last comment, fixing the rotation to the plane spanned by $(0,0,1)$ and $(a,b,c)$ is one way of fixing this problem though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the vector $V = (0, 0, 1)$ and the unit vector $W = (a, b, c)$, and the vector $U = (x, y, z)$, you want to rotate $V$ into $W$ and along with this, you want to apply the same rotation to $U$ which will result in vector $U' = (x', y', z') $

It is required in the question that the axis of rotation be perpendicular to the plane that contains $V$ and $W$.  Therefore, the unit vector along the axis is

$ u = \dfrac{ V \times W }{ \|V \times W\| } $

Since $V$ and $W$ are unit vectors, the angle of rotation $\phi$ satisfies

$ \cos(\phi) = V \cdot W $

and

$ \sin(\phi) =  \| V \times W \|  $

now, $\phi$ can be computed as $ \phi = \text{Atan2}(\cos(\phi), \sin(\phi) ) $

Now we apply the **Rodrigues' Rotation matrix** formula, which states that given an axis $u$ and an angle of rotation $\phi $ , then the rotation matrix is given by

$ R(u, \phi) = {u u}^T + (I - {u u}^T ) \cos(\phi) + S_u \sin(\phi) $

where

$S_u = \begin{bmatrix} 0 && - u_z && u_y \\ u_z && 0 && -u_x \\ -u_y && u_x && 0 \end{bmatrix} $

With this rotation matrix, we can now find $ U' $ as follows

$ U' = R \ U $

Comment: Would $R$ be the same as the matrix in this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle replacing $\phi$ with $\theta$. Sorry I'm still pretty new to matrix math in general.

Comment: Yes.  It is would be the same.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

1. Calculate the axis of rotation $v = \frac{(a,b,c)+(0,0,1)}{2} = \left(\frac{a}{2},\frac{b}{2},\frac{c+1}{2}\right)$
2. Normalize the axis of rotation $u := \frac{v}{||v||_2} := (u_x,u_y,u_z)$
3. Calculate the angle of rotation $\theta = \arccos\left(\frac{(a,b,c)\cdot(0,0,1)}{||(a,b,c)||_2||(0,0,1)||_2}\right) = \arccos\left(\frac{c}{||(a,b,c)||_2}\right) \stackrel{\text{if }||(a,b,c)||_2 = 1}{=} \arccos(c)$
4. Use the [Rotation matrix from axis and angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle) formula:

$$R = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta)+u_x^2(1-\cos(\theta)) & u_xu_y(1-\cos(\theta))-u_z\sin(\theta) & u_xu_z(1-\cos(\theta))+u_y\sin(\theta) \\
u_yu_x(1-\cos(\theta))+u_z\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)+u_y^2(1-\cos(\theta)) & u_yu_z(1-\cos(\theta))-u_x\sin(\theta) \\
u_zu_x(1-\cos(\theta))-u_y\sin(\theta) & u_zu_y(1-\cos(\theta))+u_x\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)+u_z^2(1-\cos(\theta))
\end{bmatrix}$$
5. Then, for any $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$, its rotated position will be
$$R\cdot(x,y,z)^T = R \begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: In step 2 what does the 2 in $||v||_2$ mean? I'm pretty new to this so I'm unfamiliar with the notation.

Comment: Does it just mean the length of v or does the 2 mean something?

Comment: $||v||_2$ is the simple Euclidean norm of $v$, or its length. If $v = (v_1,v_2,v_3)$, then $||v||_2 = \sqrt{v_1^2+v_2^2+v_3^2}$

Comment: The $2$ means the $2$-norm, when we *square* each number under the square root. To be fair, since this is simple Euclidean geometry, I shouldn't have used $2$, should have just wrote $||v||$ or $|v|$

Comment: Oh I see that's something new I learned. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielP Your Step 3 is incorrect.  With the choice of axis of rotation made in Step 1, the angle of rotation is $180^\circ$, and not the angle between $(0,0,1)$ and $(a,b,c)$.  The latter corresponds to an axis that the cross product of $(0,0,1)$ and $(a,b,c)$.

Comment: @DanielP If I'm not wrong the above method rotates $(0,0,1)$ to $(a,b,c)$ around $u$ which is in-between them, but this is not what I want sadly, I want the rotation to directly move $(0,0,1)$ to $(a,b,c)$ in a straight line not in a circular path of motion.

Comment: Oh I see. My bad, I misunderstood the question then.